# How to include subset of files while excluding everything else from same sub-directory?

Tags: regex, rsync

My include list is smaller than amount of files to be excluded for rsync. The directory structure is as shown below:

```
/store/app/out/content/version1/one.txt
/store/app/out/content/version1/onemore.txt
/store/app/out/content/version2/two.txt
/store/app/out/content/version3/three.txt
```

The goal is to include files in specific **versionX** directories, for example, **version1**, **version2** but not **version3** dir.

I've tried following without any success:

```
rsync -avn --delete --modify-window=2 
--include "store/app/out/content/((version1)|(version2))/*" 
--exclude "store/app/out/content/*" <from> <to>
```

Any help in right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Use. /*!(version3) inside the glob

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude URLs containing string `version3`, using `(?!)` negative lookahead.

**Regex**: [`/store/app/out/content/(?!version3).+`](https://regex101.com/r/8zo8bI/1)